# How can i Open .pdf file in java

Tags: java, swing, pdf

As I'm developing a desktop based application, there's a user manual in .pdf format which should be opened while user click on a help menu item.

I don't know the way to open .pdf file from swing application, so how can i get it open in my `jframe` or in any pdf file viewer such as acrobat reader.

Comment: Note that `Desktop.open()` requires a `File`, while a PDF distributed by the app. will typically be in a Jar, & accessible by `URL`. ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
ActionListener listener = new MyListener();
        butt.addActionListener(listener);
```

In My Listener add this

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            try {
                File myFile = new File( "path/to/file");
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // no application registered for PDFs
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nice solution, but for completeness how would you handle the "else" case above (i.e. "Desktop" is not supported)?

Answer (score 2):

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
File file = new File(path);
desktop.open(file);
```

opens file in default system viewer

Answer (score 1):

I will complement the aravindKrishna's answer and it has worked for me. I would hope this code works for somebody:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File myFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("package/file.pdf").getFile());
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    //Control the exception
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to using this `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd PDF_FILE")`. This will open a pdf in Acrobat Reader just like you double click that file.