# i want open files in my programme

Tags: java, eclipse, file

how can I (read) different types of files in my program (pdf, txt, word or excel) and display them on `JEditorPane`?

My programme is taking any type of files and open them in himself.

I already tried

```
public void displaydata(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    display.setPage(file.toURL());
}
```

I get correct data only with `txt` files.

I get strange output with `pdf`.

Comment: Java doesn't display PDF files by default, you'll need to have a look around for some view/component which can

Comment: can i open the file normaly in any pdf reader and display results in Jeditorpane??

Comment: You can use `Desktop#open` to open any file in it's associated program (if available), see [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) for more details.  But no, you won't be able to use a `JEditorPane`, it's not designed for show PDF files

Comment: if i did that is there any thing i can show data on (like i am making the program a window to see the data i opened with its file?)

Comment: You could also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761727/basic-code-to-display-a-pdf-in-an-existing-jpanel) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620222/how-can-i-open-pdf-file-in-java) or [this](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=java+swing+show+pdf)

Comment: Open any file formats... You mean you want to build a hex editor/viewer?

Comment: not exactly i was thinking in opening these files normaly by their viewers but my program view their results(i enter any file path-it opens with its supported program-the results copied in my program)

Comment: @KareemElsayed i added a comment to my below answer, added some link to library that allow render a spreadsheet as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a important point.

Every files have a different structure, this is the point of `File extention`, this is how your OS (more often) recognize the type of file and know how to open it.

You can't just open a file as a text file, and display the content as a `PDF Reader` or `Excel` would present it to you, because each software have a behvior to build the view. (This is why you can't open an mp3 file with `Microsoft Word`).

So, **in my opinion, you can't** do what you are trying to achieve. You may be able to do this, but you'll need import a `reader` library for each file type you want to open.

Comment: Lists for maven dependencies are on this page : http://www.aspose.com/blogs/aspose-products/aspose-total-product-family/archive/2014/08/12/aspose-for-maven-aspose-cloud-maven-repository.html

Comment: how to render an excell sheet to an image : http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Converting+Worksheet+to+Image

Comment: you can find some exampel for words and so on on the same web site ;)

Comment: @KareemElsayed No problems